# Why do we add properties to request object?

Tags: node.js, request, httprequest, response, middleware

I can't understand why do we add properties to request object?

As I know, the request object comes from the front end side and if any information is needed or they have, the frontend side should attach it to the request object and send it to backend side like a cookie or JWT token, etc.

And after we got that information in the backend side we can add/update more properties to the response object, like new JWT token, new session ID, etc.

But I see in backend codes, they also add properties to request object and this is vague to me. I don't know why the backend side should add something to the request? Maybe because of the internal transactions between the different middleware this happens? I mean middleware1 adds something to the request object and sends it to the middleware2 in backend side?

For example I can't understand why do we add something to `req.session` not `res.session`? Because as I understand this data should be passed to the frontend side to be added into their next request.

But if there is any other reason for adding properties to req object instead of the res object, please let me know?

Comment: Adding something to the request object is a way of adding some data per request. For example, a request may have JWT token, but the actual user object (with data like id, email, permissions, etc.) is stored in the database. If your service almost always requires a user you can load it once and attach it to the request object. Arguably there are other, better ways to do that, but this works as well.

Comment: @freakish: So you are talking about the reason I mentioned? It's because of passing the request between internal middleware/function/software in the backend server and there is no other reason for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Mutating the request object by adding additional properties is the primary method of passing additional data between middlewares within Express.  Since the request and response are passed to every middleware, this is the only chain that gives you continuity between middlewares.

(You will also see some passed on the response object as well, but in general it's most common to see it on `req`).

Note that you need to avoid collisions with Express's properties and methods as well as the underlying connection objects from Node.